# shoppingCartProductAdd SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no ‘key’ property

Tags: php, api, magento, soap

I’m having trouble with Magento API SOAP V2, and I don’t know if it is a bug or something wrong with the parameters. 
I’m trying to add a bundled product to cart that have one option with three checkboxes that looks like this in a array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 69,
            [qty] => 1,
            [bundle_option] => Array
                (
                    [22] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 59
                        )

                ),
            [bundle_option_qty] => array(),
            [options] => array(),
            [links] => array()
        )
)
```

I've already tried with:

```
[product_id] => 69
[sku] => esp_topo_teselas
[qty] => 1
[bundle_option] => Array
    (
        [22] => Array
            (
                [key] => 22
                [value] => 60
            )

    )

[bundle_option_qty] => Array
    (
        [22] => 1
            )
    )

[options] => NULL,
[links] => NULL
```

successfully, but it only adds one of the selections, then I've tried like this:

```
[bundle_option] => Array
        (
            [22] => Array
                (
                    [key] => 22
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 59
                            [1] => 60
                        )
                )

        )
```

with the following error message: `Please specify product option(s)`

Any clues?
Thanks in advance!